# Update ListView in React Native

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native, datasource

I now there is several proposed solutions but cannot get them to work. I have problems updating the listview by making a copy of the old array correctly. 
My solution so far (which doesnt work :-() dont rerender the listview.

```
const data = [{
            id: 1,
            selected: true,
        }, {
            id: 2,
            selected: false,
        }, {
            id: 3,
            selected: false,
        }]

        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data),
            data: data,
        }
```

To update the row i use this code:

```
   _updateRow = (rowData, rowID) => {
    let newArray = this.state.data.slice();

    newArray.map((o, index) => {
        if (o.id = rowData.id){
            o.selected = true;
        }
        else {
            o.selected = false;
        }
    })


    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newArray),
        data: newArray
    })
}
```

I want to change a property (selected) from index to true and all the other objects (selected) to false. 
Hope someone can help. Looking for the cleanest solution.

Regards

Comment: o.id = rowData.id or o.id == rowData.id ?

Comment: Oops. o.id == rowData.id  ofcourse :-)

Answer (score 2):

YEAH!!!
Solved it.
Here are the code:

```
_updateRow = (rowData, rowID) => {
    let newArray = this.state.data.slice();

    newArray.map((o, index) => {
            newArray[index] = {...o, selected: true};
        else
            newArray[index] = {...o, selected: false};

    })

    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newArray),
        data: newArray
    })
}
```

Any one with a nicer solution?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the code below?

```js
_updateRow = (rowData) => {
    let newArray = [].concat(this.state.data);

    newArray.map((o, index) => {
      return {...o, selected: o.id === rowData.id}
    });

    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newArray),
        data: newArray
    })
}
```